# best way to debug a gzip error

Tags: java, gzip, gzipinputstream

we have an app that works great most of the time.

notably it works always if we turn off compression (gzip) between the server and client when sending data out for rendering.

when we have gzip turned on (preferred mode) - then sometimes - rarely but sometimes - we experience a failure to uncompress the stream as follows:

```
</esql:row></esql:sql></esql:transaction>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>>
```

note the end where we get a double >>.

we can duplicate the behavior on a couple query responses, but not all, and not on all environments.

we think the problem has been narrowed down to the server side that is compressing the stream because we have Firefox and javas `GZIPInputStream` both decrypting the stream the same way (and we don't think Firefox uses `GZIPInputStream`)

any tips on how to debug this further? any known bugs in `GZIP`?

thanks for anything.

Comment: There is no known bug in gzip or zlib that would produce a copied character at the end.  There is likely a bug in the server code.

Comment: Can you capture an example offending stream between the server and client?